# Postar em fan page com facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook

Fiz um script no qual posto automaticamente em uma fan page no facebook, o script funciona, mas a postagem só fica visivel para o usuário que postou (que é o admin da fan page), no login estou pedindo as permissões abaixo:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,publish_stream'));
```

E estou postando com o seguinte código:

```
$args = array(
 'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],
 'link' => 'http://www.sitelink.com.br/alguma-coisa',
 'method' => 'post'
);

$facebook->api("/99999999999/feed","post",$args);
```

Alguém sabe se no login eu tenho que pedir alguma permissão a mais para aparecer como público as postagens?

Tenho que configurar alguma coisa a mais na app do facebook lá no developers?

Comment: O app estava como desenvolvimento ainda, por isso somente o admin visualizava as postagens. Coloquei o app em live e esta funcionando normalmente. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente a permissão publish_actions. Note que esta permissão é do tipo 'extended', e será requisitada separadamente ao usuário.

Para mais informações: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-extended